# is vector < list <marker> > the right way to approach this?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to solve a problem for work and am a novice programmer. I have three files, both tab delimited.

File1 has two fields: *Marker_id* & *position* and this file is sorted by position (0-26) and then Marker_id is in an order that is a consequence of another application but is not alphabetical.The order of Marker_id is important because the goal of my program is to find a starting Marker_id and count the number of Markers between that and an ending Marker. This file contains nearly 2,500,000 entries.

File2 has one field *Marker_id* This is the same Marker_id that is used in File1, but this file contains only around 2,200,000 entries. This file is a list of "active" markers or markers that should be counted by my program.

File3 has fields *position* *starting_marker* *ending marker* *number_markers* and other fields. I need to basically update the number_markers field by counting the number of markers between start and end.

I already have code that reads file1 into

```
vector< list<marker> >;
```

where marker is a struct:

```
struct MARKER{
 string snp_id;
 bool included;
 MARKER(string temp_id) : snp_id(temp_id), included(false) { }
};
```

And the position (0-26) from file one specifies what index in the vector to store the markers. I also successfully update the count in file3 with the number of markers between start and stop.

However, I'm having trouble implementing a function to trim my list to only "active markers." I was going to simply do MARKER.included(true); for entries in file2 until I realized file2 does not contain *position* and therfore, I'd have to search every list at each vector index. This is possible, I just feel like it would be incredibly slow with so many entries.

I'm trying to think of alternatives such as storing file1 in a map where the key is Marker_id, but needing to keep Marker_id's in original order for counting is hanging me up.

Does anyone have any advice? Thanks.

UPDATE (example files):

```
***File1***
Marker_id                position
  test_marker_1              1
  test_marker_2              1 
  test_marker_3              1
  test_marker_4              1
  test_marker_5              1
  test_marker_6              1
  test_marker_7              1
  test_marker_8              1   
  test_marker_9              1
```

.

```
***File2***
Marker_id         C20020.Log R Ratio    C20020.B Allele Freq
test_marker_1         0.0180                       0.0010
test_marker_3        -0.0340                       0.5000
test_marker_4         0.0500                       0.0700
test_marker_5         0.0500                       0.0700
test_marker_6         0.0500                       0.0700
test_marker_7         0.0500                       0.0700
test_marker_9         0.0500                       0.0700
```

Note: test_marker_2 and test_marker_8 are omitted from file 2 and therefore, will not be included in counts.

```
***File3***
position  copy_num  sampleID   startMarker     endMarker          conf         num_Markers
   1         4      C20020    test_marker_1     test_marker_3     1774.967          0
   1         3      C20020    test_marker_3     test_marker_5      17.967           0
   1         0      C20020    test_marker_7     test_marker_9    107.967           0
```

.

```
***My desired output***
position  copy_num  sampleID   startMarker     endMarker          conf         num_Markers
   1         4      C20020    test_marker_1     test_marker_3     1774.967          2
   1         3      C20020    test_marker_3     test_marker_5      17.967           3
   1         0      C20020    test_marker_7     test_marker_9    107.967           2
```

As it stands now, I have everything functioning except my counts would be 3 for all three examples since I do not exclude those Markers not found in file2.

Comment: In general, unless you have a really good reason to do so, you should use `std::vector<>` for all your sequence containers (i.e. rather than `std::list<>`)

Comment: wouldn't the addition of entries be more efficient storing each Marker_id in a list? I figured using vectors would require resizing them for each entry... meaning ~2,500,000 resizings.

Comment: No, `std::vector` grows exponentially, it doesn't resize on every insertion. Assuming a growth factor of 2 (which is typical for standard library implementations) you'd only get log2(2500000) resizings for insertions, which is about 22. If you use `std::vector::reserve()` you can reduce that to one.

Comment: Interesting, think I'll go ahead and change that to vector <vector <MARKER> >; thanks!

Comment: @Robert this may be *much easier than you think. If you get a chance, post *actual sample data* from each file (a few lines from each will suffice) **as an update to your question (bottom)**. (i.e. not in a comment). You can describe it 'till the sun goes down, but it is no substitute for real workable data if some is available.

Comment: Can I also ask, why use vectors for sequence containers rather than lists? Is this just convention or is there some benefit of vectors vs lists?

Comment: @Robert: usually it's performance benefit, because of better cache locality and less memory allocations

Comment: @WhozCraig have you had a chance to look at the example files I added? I attempted to search every vector(formerly lists) for the Marker_id and set it's included = true; But after leaving my program run overnight and through the next day I think that method takes too long with the number of entries I have or I messed up that code. I feel like there must be an easier to tackle the problem but still haven't come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of approaches come to mind.

You could sort files 1 and 2 by marker id (temporary copies, of course), then could easily determine the markers that are in file 1 but not in file 2 in a single pass.  You could then use this "exclusion list" to determine markers to ignore in the other part of the algorithm.  Per your numbers, this would be ~300,000 items, which could be inserted into a hash map for quick lookups.

Of course, if you have oodles of memory, you could always just put **all** of file 2 into a hash map, and use it in the same way.

If memory is a real issue, but the marker values are such that they define a complete space (e.g. numbers 1 to 10 million, or whatever), where markers can be mapped to offsets, then you could create a bit map of the entire space, with 1's only for markers that are active.  Again, using this bitmap to exclude those markers that are to be ignored.

Basically, as long as you can get a constant-time check for the include/exclude test, you're laughing.